# Input through pipe in separate terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Hi I am trying to build a program in bash. The idea is that I would have open two terminals. One would take the input with a pipe `cat > pipe` . The other terminal would be running a bash script with a while true loop and read the input from the pipe. The input would be stored to a variable and further action would occur depending on what is stored inside. This is what I tried.

The program gets the pipe name as an argument and it is stored to the variable pipe.

```
while true; do
      input=$(cat<$pipe)
      if [ "$input" == "exit" ]; then
           exit 0
      fi
done
```

I have tried to input an exit string throught the pipe but the program does not stop as it should. If the variable does not get any value from the pipe how would I correct that? Or is something else wrong that prevents the exit from happening?

Comment: thank you totally forgot while I was writting thought I asked at the start

Comment: try running it with `#!/usr/bin/bash -vx` (or whatever your shell add -x) as topmost line for debugging. Maybe add output here if it doesn't guide you to a solution

Comment: In the second terminal's  `cat<$pipe` what is value of `$pipe` set to?

Comment: hi after running the test I got this [Output](http://imgur.com/n6dBn9t)

Comment: @sjsam in the second terminal where the input is I have it set as pipe so the command that runs is cat > pipe. Here I input it as pipe than do pipe="$1" and try to run it

Comment: @Tenebris : And the argument  to reading script is the file-name itself right?

Comment: @sjsam yes it is the file-name of the pipe

Comment: Do an `echo "$input"` just after `$input=$(cat<$pipe)` and that explains why the script is infinite..

Comment: @sjsam hi i tried and when I close the pipe on the input end I get all the echoes at one time. How would I get them at input time? And the if than does not really work too.

Comment: @Tenebris : See my second solution. Suppose you don't type faster than the second script, you should get expected results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second script should be something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe="$1" # Here $1 is full path to the file pipe as you have confirmed
while true
  do
input=$(cat<"$pipe")
if [[ $input =~ exit ]] #original line was if [ "$input" == "exit" ]
  then
exit 0
fi
done
```

Remember `$(cat<"$pipe")` will store the entire file as a string. So, even though you have the word `exit` somewhere down in the `pipe` file the original condition `if [ "$input" == "exit" ]` will be false except the case when the first word you enter for `cat>pipe` itself is "exit".

A little tweakish solution is do a regex match `(=~)` as I have done but this solution is not very reliable because if you enter something like "I don't wanna exit", for `cat>pipe` the second script will exit.

A second solution would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe="$1"
while true; do
input=$(tail -n1 "$pipe") #checking only the last line
if [[ "$input" == "exit" ]] #original if condition
  then
exit 0
fi
done
```